# malformed migrations using EF code first on a MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am building an application using C#, .NET 4.5, EF6 Code First, MySQL.

When I add a migration, the code that is generated is malformed. The "using" statements are within the namespace block. Here is an example:

**Wrong:** (generated by EF)

```
namespace RevoHost.BL.Entities.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class Permissions : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
            // etc...
```

**I expected:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace RevoHost.BL.Entities.Migrations
{

    public partial class Permissions : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
            // etc...
```

It's easy enough to fix manually, but it's still annoying. I've searched far and wide to find a solution, but so far I was unable to come up with one.

I have this attribute on my DbContext class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

And I configured the migrations like so:

```
namespace RevoHost.BL.Entities.Migrations
{
  internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RevoHost.BL.Entities.RevoContext>
  {
    public Configuration()
    {
      SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
      CodeGenerator = new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
      AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: It's not really malformed though is it?  It will still work, just that the usings are local to the namespace, which shouldn't matter as each migration is in its own file anyway

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if it were that simple. Usings within a namespace would be perfectly acceptabe if the compiler accepted it. The fact of the matter is  that in C# the usings are per file and so must be outside of any code blocks (including the usings).

Comment: My namespace has dots in them (RevoHost.BL.Entities.Migrations). If comment that out and instead write `namespace something` (without dots) it is accepted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is going on. Indeed, as Thewads mentioned in his comment, the code in itself is not malformed and perfectly legal. Because this is my first EF6 project that runs on MySQL instead of SQL Server, I immediately assumed MySQL was the culprit, which obviously it wasn't.

I looked at another project that uses EF6 code first with migrations. That code is exactly the same. Next I examined the exact error I got from the compiler.

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'CodeDom' does not exist in the namespace 'RevoHost.BL.Entities.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(and another 9 like those)

I had defined an entity in a namespace called RevoHost.BL.Entities.**System**.
This causes a naming collision; the compiler finds the System namespace in RevoHost.BL.Entities before it finds the global System namespace.

So, in short, the answer is, make sure you do not define a namespace that collides with the **System** namespace.